# ExtJS grid - how to focus on added row?

Tags: json, extjs, grid

I have a grid(gridpanel) and data in it which I read from json query. After I added new bussines object(row) - I send him in json format to server, write to DB, and reload all grid. How I can focus on currently added row(b/o) after that? I will be very cool if I return added id at the json answer and grid take it and focus on row with added id.
Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How is your data being added (append-mode or not?).  You can do `grid_panel.getView().focusRow(row)` on the length of the data array in the store, which will focus on the "last" row that was inserted.  Also, you could hook into the `rowsinserted` event of `GridView`, and `focusRow` on the `lastRow` parameter that's passed in there.